# How do I see logs of critical errors of specific pages without enabling public debug for everyone?

Tags: php, debug, 500-internal-error

I have a site that works well in production, say with N pages currenly being used by users.

I am doing some PHP scripting in one specific page and I want to debug some data. Usually in projects not related to wordpress (for example in projects in Symfony) I voluntarily throw exceptions on the sad-path.

Let's say I force a `500 server error` with this code that is **only** executed in **this** particular page:

```
class OfferCacheGenerator
{
    private function fetchAllOffersJsonFromRemoteFile() : string
    {
        $result = // Whatever remote fetch
        if( $this->isWellFormatted( $result ) )
        {
            $allOffersAsJson = // Whatever post-processing
        }
        else
        {
            throw new \Exception( 'Format is incorrect.' );
        }

        return $allOffersAsJson;
    }

    private function isWellFormatted( string $result ) : bool
    {
        return false; // TODO: Do the real format checking.
    }
}
```

When I do this in wordpress I can see this in the browser:

```
There has been a critical error on this website
Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.
```

- This is good in the sense that give mes the expected `500 server error`.
- Now I want to see somewhere the text `Format is incorrect.` casted by the exception.

## Environment

- I am using the plugin `Code Snippets` by Code Snippets Pro to inject the code (ie: I'm not touching any file inside the hosting).
- My hosting does not have SSH. It does have a web-based file manager but I can't enter the server to do things like `tail` and so on.

## Desire

- I want to see my 500-server-error logs (in this case the string `Format is incorrect.` somewhere.
- I don't want to set all the site in debug mode, as that could potentially leak info to the general public, I want to debug only this page whose URL is not yet known by the general public.

## Question

Where may I read the php exception logs?